# How do I inject a spring (2.5) bean into a hibernate (3) entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dependency-injection

How can I use spring to inject a bean into a hibernate entity? I am using spring 2.5 with hibernate 3.

I can see how to do this in spring 3, but can it be done in spring 2.5?

In the example I want to inject the `UtillBean` into `Stuff.stuffUtill`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUFF")
public class Stuff {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUFF_ID")
    private Long stuffID;

    private UtillBean stuffUtill;

}

public class UtillBean {
    ...
}
```

***update:** For this situation, this is the design I am stuck with.*

Comment: Injecting a business class inside an entity class? I would rethink this design.

Comment: Again, I would rethink the design. Your entity should not perform any business logic to begin with. The fact that *you can* doesn't mean *you should*.

Comment: I agree with @LuiggiMendoza. That is  a bad design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `@Configurable` annotation (since 2.0).

See http://blog.springsource.org/2008/01/23/new-improvements-in-domain-object-dependnecy-injection-feature/ spring source post for more info.